# Restricting the number of nickname per ID

Tags: javascript

I desperately need a javascript function to restrict the number of nicknames per ID, to prevent fakes on a game.

Everytime a new nickname joins, it creates a new account using his name.
Everyone has an browser authentication ID called, player.id

What I would like is to allow only 1 player.name for 1 player.id

Ex. If I join the room with the nickname X, this player.name is linked to my player.id.
And if 5 days later I join with the name Y but with the same ID, I get kicked and invited to back my original name X.

Please help me out I would be so greatful.

Comment: "allow only 1 player.name for 1 player.ip" ... you realise that two people using two difference devices who are, perhaps, in the same house or sharing the same wifi connection, will likely have the same public-facing IP address (because of [NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation))? So if you do this, you would stop them from playing against each other. Are you ok with that? Also do you realise that many ISPs operate dynamic IP assignment, so the IP might change regularly, and so you can't guarantee the IP always refers to the same person (or people)?

Comment: It would make a lot more sense just to get people to register and log in, and manage their identity that way. Anyway...you've tagged this as JavaScript...are you talking about server-side NodeJS? because I'm not really sure how this requirement would make any sense in a browser environment (where the code would be running on the client, not the server)

Comment: Home IP are usually dynamic, it gets recycled often so if you find the same IP five days apart, they are probably from different users.

Comment: @ADyson I edited my post meanwhile because we also can use the player.id which is the browser authentication ID.

Comment: If you need help with code, it's really paramount to post said code.

Comment: @FranciscoMarão Depends on the ISP. In the US, most broadband ISPs assign the same IP to the same customer for a long time. They don't guarantee permanence, but they're usually consistent.

Comment: @ADyson I know I may not be helping you a lot, it's a online game called Haxball that allow you to handle servers with your own javascript code in a page called Headless, that way you can make your own bot for the game.